# Watson Virtual Agent vs IBM Watson Conversation

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-virtual-agent

I have created a virtual agent connected to a Watson conversation.  I have one dialog tree that works perfectly in IBM Watson Conversation testing.

Salary inquiry -> Are you company or external -> company input -> company response (per the dialog tree, on the second level).

But when I ask the same exact questions/responses in the same sequence in the virtual agent, I am getting a different response.

Salary inquiry -> Are you company or external -> company input -> about company response (on the first level of the dialog tree)

Answer (score 0):

We recently delivered a fix that corrected an issue with our "off-topic" logic. Can you please retry this scenario and let us know if it is resolved for you? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did a little bit of recoding at the same time, so not sure which worked, but it is now working properly.